# How to deploy compressed files more than 100 mb on GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, pycaffe

I have written a Google Cloud function. Files are around 100 mb.
How do I deploy it? It has a file .caffemodel which is 128 mb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the GCP quotas for Cloud Functions found here:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas

we see that the maximum deployment size for a function is 100MB and can *not* be increased (through quotas).  Let us remember the nature of Cloud Functions ... by and large short duration execution times where the number of instances available for processing concurrent work is dynamic and can scale to zero.

Cloud Functions is at the far right of the spectrum of ease of use but that comes at the expense of flexibility (in this case deployment size).  The next option in line is the product called Cloud Run.  Cloud Run also provides dynamic instance number scaling including scaling to zero.  However it (arguably) needs more work to get running.  With Cloud Run, you build a Docker image that is then instantiated as needed to process incoming work requests.   The Docker image has far fewer restrictions on what it can do.  Specifically, the container should be able to accomodate 128 MB data files (trivially)

Comment: Thanks. But on https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas url it shows that max deployment size is 500 mb in case of uncompressed files. So how to deploy with uncompressed files? Any idea?

Comment: My guess is that it is 100MB for your uploaded package and a further 400MB **available** (bringing the total to 500MB) for your own uploaded package PLUS the storage that is needed when your package dependencies (modules) as described in package.json are dynamically pulled in.  So YOU get to upload 100MB and the total amount of disk storage that your complete package may use is 500MB.